# Excel indexing to get column header from criteria

Tags: excel, indexing, match, offset, index-match

Good afternoon,

I have a query an Excel query that I'm currently struggling to even start working through:

Setup:

I have the following 2 rows of a much larger table where I want to input a "Grade for each row:

```
   Gender   Round   Score   Grade
    Male   Albion    550    
   Female  Windsor   894
```

I somehow have to extract the Grade from the following table, where Grade is technically the column headers:

```
Gender  Round   GMB MB   B  1st 2nd 3rd
Male    Albion  890 840 746 590 435 257
Female  Windsor 931 895 828 713 584 402
```

For instance the formula would identify that:

A male Albion with score 550 would be a 2nd grade.
A female Windsor with score 894 would be a B grade.

Can this be done, and how? Usually I'd show my working but I'm completely out of my depth with this.

Thanks in advance.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you have Office 365

- Name your big table `Scores`

```
=LET(x,INDEX(FILTER(Scores,(Scores[Gender]=K8)*(Scores[Round]=L8)),0, SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(Scores)-2,,3)),
     y, INDEX(SORT(x),MATCH(M8,SORT(x))),
     z, XMATCH(y,x),
     res, INDEX(Scores[#Headers],z+2),res)
```

[image]

*With an earlier version, I'd suggest VBA or Power Query*